# Consume REST services on Android, easiest way?

Tags: java, android, json, rest, jax-rs

I have a REST Service and want to consume it with Android. The service (JAX-RS) publishes JSON data. So the main question are:

- is there a good ready-to-use solution for Android, if not, what else can you recommend?
- I'd like to transfer POJOs, how could I realize that? Is GSON a suitable approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since API Level 8 you could use [`AndroidHTTPClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) , or for earlier APIs you can use `DefaultHttpClient` with no problems, and send data using `HttpPost` or `HttpGet`. For encoding data in `JSON`, yes `GSON` is a good approach, but I think that [`org.json`](http://www.json.org/) would be more easy to use.

Comment: Thank you. In what way is org.json easier to use? Aren't there just a few lines of code in either technologies needed?

Comment: Maybe it is just my opinion but I like more JSON. It is also included in the Android SDK, so no need for additional librarie.

Comment: hm I thought GSON is for de/serializing objects to/from JSON, it is not an alternative to JSON itself. Did I get this wrong?

Comment: you are right. with JSON you will have to implement for your POJO's a `toJson()` method that will convert your object to a json. and I assume you will just send that JSON, so you wont need those objects back, so no need for deserialization. also, when receiving a JSON response you will just parse that, and create maybe another type of POJOs.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Android has a RestTemplate that is pretty easy to use.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html

For example:

```
String url = "http://mypretendservice.com/events";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Event[] events = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Event[].class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Resteasy-mobile is a perfect solution (https://github.com/tdiesler/resteasy-mobile)

It's basically full blown resteasy (which has client framework) but uses Apache HTTP Client rather than HttpURLConnection (which doesn't exist on android)

Here is more information about usage (http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.1.GA//userguide/html_single/index.html#RESTEasy_Client_Framework)

Here is for the maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy.mobile</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-mobile</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

A little sample code on android side

```
    public class RestServices {
    static RegisterSVC registerSVC;
    static PushSVC pushSVC;
    static TrackerSVC trackerSVC;

    RestServices() {
        RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());
    }

    public static RegisterSVC getRegisterSVC() {
        return ProxyFactory.create(RegisterSVC.class,"http://143.248.194.236:8080/notification");

    }

    public static PushSVC getPushSVC() {
        return ProxyFactory.create(PushSVC.class,"http://143.248.194.236:8080/notification");
    }

    public static TrackerSVC getTrackerSVC() {
        return ProxyFactory.create(TrackerSVC.class,"http://143.248.194.236:8080/notification");
    }
}
```

JAX-RS service definition (PushSVC.java) on both android and server side

```
@Path("/mobile")
public interface PushSVC {
    /*
    Sample
    curl --data '{"collapseKey":"asdf","contentList":{"aaaa":"you","ssss":"you2"}}' -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' -v http://localhost:8080/notification/mobile/11111/send
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/{uuid}/send")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    String sendPush( MessageVO message, @PathParam("uuid") String uuid);

}
```

Model MessageVO definition

```
public class MessageVO {
    String collapseKey;
    HashMap<String, String> contentList;

    public MessageVO() {
    }

    public MessageVO(String collapseKey) {
        this.collapseKey = collapseKey;
        contentList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public void put(String key, String value)
    {
        this.contentList.put(key,value);
    }

    public String getCollapseKey() {
        return collapseKey;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getContentList() {
        return contentList;
    }
}
```

This is method invocation on android

```
public class Broadcast extends AsyncTask<Context,Void,Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Context... contexts) {
        MessageVO message = new MessageVO("0");
        message.put("tickerText","Ticker ne` :D");
        message.put("contentTitle","Title ne` :D");
        message.put("contentText","Content ne` :D");
        RestServices.getPushSVC().sendPush(message,TrackInstallation.id(contexts[0]).toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is pretty simple and all written codes are reusable, boilerplate code is near to non-existence

Hope this help everybody.